# The meaning of the sulfite anion attached to the benzene ring

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, aromatic-compounds

I needed to work with PEDOT:PSS solution, so I also looked up it's chemical composition and the wikipedia page threw up this pic.[image]

I need to understand how the sulfite anion is connected to the benzene ring in the structure on the right. I have studied it in chemistry in my school days but I have not really used it afterwards, hence I have forgotten. Your explanations will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your wondering about the bond, the line going to the center means that the sulfonyl group is attached at any available position (2, 3, or 4) on the ring, and no particular position is given.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to use this compound mixture to displace the Se/S ion from CdSe or CdS

Comment: I suppose it* could*. To what extent I cannot say. I can say It will have *similar* acid/base chemistry to sulfate ions or better yet similar to **p-Toluenesulfonic acid**